# video in unity 4.6 (mobile)

Tags: video, unity-game-engine

We use Unity 4.6.1f

We are currently working on a project where we need a video to play on a mobile device.
We got the video uploaded and on PC it shows us that it downloads the video as well on the first time we try and access it. When we tried using it on mobile the only response we got was a short black screen followed by nothing. We know that the script works since it has worked before and we didn't change anything about it but the filename for the video. We tried different video formats and a friend of mine said that it might be a problem with the Unity Meta files (since the code was used in a different Unity project before).

Comment: even if it worked before. I have to ask. Are you using the Pro version or the free version?

Comment: We found the solution. We needed to put the videos in a special/dedicated Streaming Assets folder (which is in the "general" assets folder of the project).

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution. We needed to put the videos in a special/dedicated Streaming Assets folder (which is in the "general" assets folder of the project)